# With P1141R1 voted in, how many types are deduced from multiple deduced parameters with the same constraint?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++-concepts, c++20

According to Concepts TS, while an unconstrained deduced parameter yield new template type parameter each time, constrained deduced parameters yield only one template type parameter per constraint:

```
[](auto a, auto b) // IS-A
[]<class ArgA, class ArgB>(ArgA a, ArgB b)

[](Constraint a, Constraint b) // IS-A
[]<Constraint Type>(Type a, Type b)
```

Now, the [P1141R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1141r1.html) was voted in (see [Herb Sutter's Trip Report](https://herbsutter.com/2018/11/13/trip-report-fall-iso-c-standards-meeting-san-diego/)) and it re-introduces the short syntax for constrained deduced parameters with "adjective syntax" for constrained auto:

```
void fun(Constraint auto a, Constraint auto b);
```

with notion, that "The appearance of `auto` (including `Constraint auto`) in a parameter list tells us that we are dealing with a function template."

There is, however, no information on how many separate types such syntax would yield. So, the question is: for two constrained deduced parameters with the same constraint (as above), would there be a template with one type parameter, or are the rules relaxed due to presence of `auto` keyword?

**Edit:** template type <del>argument</del> parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People should really stop writing misleading trip reports with links to outdated papers, at least without a giant flashing neon pink disclaimer. The paper voted in is P1141R2, which will be publicly available in a few weeks. The approved design is roughly parts 1, 3, and 4 of P1141R1.

You get independent binding, i.e., two template parameters in your example:

> An abbreviated function template is equivalent to a function template
>   (17.6.5) whose *template-parameter-list* includes one invented type
>   *template-parameter* for each occurrence of a placeholder type in the
>   *decl-specifier-seq* of a *parameter-declaration* in the function’s
>   parameter-type-list, in order of appearance.

This has been the expected direction since at least early this year.

Comment: "*People should really stop writing misleading trip reports with links to outdated papers, at least without a giant flashing neon pink disclaimer.*" Well, maybe the committee should actually put those papers up in a timely fashion, rather than waiting several *weeks* just to update some weblinks. C++ users want/deserve to know what happened at the meeting quickly, not after a couple of weeks whenever someone gets around to it. And if they can't be bothered to update links quickly, then they shouldn't be surprised that people trying to inform the community will link to older papers.

Comment: R2 just adds wording - the real issue is that "independent binding" has just been tacitly assumed as the direction for a year, so P1141 (outside of the wording) never calls attention to this.

Comment: @Barry It also knocked out two of the five parts. There's nary a mention of that in the post.

Comment: @T.C. Yeah, that one's fair :-)

Answer (score 3):

This declaration:

```
void fun(Constraint auto a, Constraint auto b);
```

means that we do so-called "independent binding".

It means the same thing as the longer *partial-concept-id* syntax:

```
template <Constraint _T, Constraint _U>
void fun(_T a, _U b);
```

and the even longer full requires-clause syntax:

```
template <typename _T, typename _U>
    requires Constraint<_T> && Constraint<_U>
void fun(_T a, _U b);
```

except that you do not have access to the names `_T` and `_U` (if you need those type names, you will need to resort to one of the longer syntax options).

---

For a lengthy list of arguments as to why "independent binding" is a better choice than "consistent binding", see [P0464](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0464r2.html): Revisiting the meaning of `foo(ConceptName, ConceptName)`.

Comment: And they are not technically the same thing (functionally equivalent but not equivalent), which is another change from the TS.

Comment: @T.C. The TS had them actually equivalent? Like I could declare terse and define unterse?

Comment: Indeed. They took them out when they merged the TS.